# Using delegates on the same file in two different classes

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

so i have this two classes in the same file and a delegate like this

```
protocol LocationSelectionDelegate {
    func didSelectLocation(name:String)
}
Class OneViewController:UIViewController{
    var locationDelegate : LocationSelectionDelegate!

    func viewDidLoad(){
    locationPicker.pickCompletion = { (pickedLocationItem) in
       // Do something with the location the user picked.

       self.locationDelegate.didSelectLocation(name:pickedLocationItem.name)
      }
   }

}

Class Two:UITableViewCell,LocationSelectionDelegate{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let oneViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "oneViewController") as! OneViewController
        oneViewController.locationDelegate = self
   }
   func didSelectLocation(name: String) {
       selectedLocation = name
   }
}
```

so i have these structure and the `locationPicker.pickCompletion` is a closure from another view which returns the location the user picked now i am trying to pass that selected location name to the second class and all this code is on the same file and when i run this code it gives an error saying `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` pointing to this line `self.locationDelegate.didSelectLocation(name:pickedLocationItem.name)`
so what am i doing wrong here and how can fix this?

Comment: the delegate is nil as you are not getting the actual reference of your OneViewcontroller, you are instantiating a new OneViewController and setting its delegate.

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: Where do you use the ClassTwo ?

Comment: both of the are on the same file its a UITableViewCell

Comment: no, it doesn't matter where you put the classes. Is there any relation between these two classes ? Do you use Class Two in OneViewController class ?You need to pass the reference of OneViewController to the  ClassTwo. You can do this in many ways. One simple way is to declare a variable var oneVc : OneViewController? in classTwo, and set it from OneViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put the classes. You need to pass the reference of OneViewController to the ClassTwo. You can do this in many ways. One simple way is to declare a variable

```
Class Two:UITableViewCell,LocationSelectionDelegate{

   var oneVc : OneViewController?{ 
      didSet{
          //Only set the locationDelegate when there is an actual value in oneVc variable
          oneVc.locationDelegate = self
      }
   }
   func didSelectLocation(name: String) {
       selectedLocation = name
   }
}
```

in classTwo, and set it from OneViewController .

Incase you are using the ClassTwo as table cell in OneViewController, then you can do this in the cellforRow method .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your_identifier", for: indexPath) as! ClassTwo
   cell.oneVc = self
   return cell
}
```